# Module import error while embedding python using pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to run an embedded Python project from within a cpp file. I have successfully run a very simple Python file with the .cpp file before. However, when I try to run this Python project, it gives an error which I will paste below. This Python project has a main.py file, which imports functions from other .py files (`from file1 import function2`, for example).

My .cpp file is as below:

```
#include "additionals/pybind11/include/pybind11/pybind11.h"
#include "additionals/pybind11/include/pybind11/embed.h"
#include "additionals/pybind11/include/pybind11/eval.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace py = pybind11;

int main() {
  //std::cout << "Current Working Directory: " << std::filesystem::current_path() << std::endl;
  py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
  py::print("Hello, World!");
  py::object scope = py::module_::import("__main__").attr("__dict__");
  py::eval_file("/radar-imaging-dataset/brateesh/pybind_example2/src/cpp/shenron_package-main/main.py", scope);
  //py::eval_file("arr.py", scope);
  
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error on the terminal:

```
Hello, World!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
  what():  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lidar'

At:
  /radar-imaging-dataset/brateesh/pybind_example2/src/cpp/shenron_package-main/main.py(8): <module>

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Main.py has a line, `from lidar import some_function`. lidar.py is a file in the same folder as main.py. Also, just to check, I have run the Python project on its own, and it works as expected. It's just when I run it as an embedded program that it gives this error. How can I run this?

I have tried to give the absolute paths of the main.py file instead of relative paths, but it did not work. In the simple Python file that I ran successfully, I have seen that I could import numpy and torch successfully. So apparently, it's importing from other files that are giving problems. Please tell me any other information that's needed, and I'll add it.

Comment: Remember that `import` pulls from the current working directory, NOT from the directory that holds the source file.  I suspect you need to `chdir` to the folder containing `main.py`, then it will work.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you, could you expand a bit more on that? When I used a standalone .py file, the .py file was in the same folder as the executable. But now, instead of the single .py file, there is a folder containing the multiple python files.

Comment: Let's say you're in a terminal.  Let's say you are in a folder called `project` that has a subfolder called `code` that contains `main.py` and `lidar.py`.  You can run that code by doing `python code/main.py`, but it will not find `import lidar` because that file is not present in `project`, which is the "working directory".  You would need to `cd code` and do `python main.py`.  NOW it will work.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks very much. I made it work after changing all locations in my python code. Every location now assumes that the current working directory is the one outside (project in your example), not the directory of the source code(code in your example).